# php-mongodb instalation version

Tags: 18.04, php, mongodb

I use

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

and I expect to get a php mongodb extension version 1.6, but get 1.3.4

apt-get update, apt-get upgrade not help me. If i install with pecl, composer don't see mongodb-extension, and command

```
php -m
```

doesn't show mongodb

Comment: @ojw php-mongodb (1.6.1-4build1) will be available from the official Ubuntu repositories in [Ubuntu 20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php-mongodb). So probably wait until release and upgrade to 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

To install the latest version of php-mongodb:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php-mongodb
```

You will not get the latest version by just using the method you outline above.  The standard php-mongodb pacakge for Ubuntu 18.04 can be seen by running:

`apt search php-mongodb`, which outputs:

> php-mongodb/bionic 1.3.4-1build1 amd64
>
> MongoDB driver for PHP

Therefore the standard package bundled with Ubuntu is 1.3.4.  To get a later version you will have to use an unsupported package from this [untrusted Personal Package Archive](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) (PPA), as per the instructions above.

Answer (score 1):

If latest php-mongo driver is not available in repository, you can download its source code, compile and install it.
Here are steps you need to follow and execute commands in terminal.

Make sure that you have development libraries required to compile source code.

```
sudo apt install build-essentials
```

Download php-mongo source code from its [releases page](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/releases). Here I have downloaded 1.6.0 version of php-mongo sourcecode , compilation steps are valid for any version.

```
wget https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/archive/1.6.0.zip
unzip 1.6.0.zip
cd mongo-php-library-1.6.0
phpize
sudo ./configure
sudo make all && sudo make install
```